is there any problem with using next js as client and nodejs , express as server
Building a MERN Stack Hospital Appointment System with Next.js
Question:
I'm developing a hospital appointment booking system with:

Appointment Booking
Video Consultations
Chat Bot
Real-time customer service

I plan to use:

Client Side: Next.js
Server Side: Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB

Questions:

Real-Time Features: Is Next.js suitable for implementing real-time features like chat and video? Any recommended libraries or tools?

Integration: How well does Next.js integrate with a MERN stack backend? Any best practices or considerations?

Styling and Structuring: Tips for styling and structuring this kind of complex application?


Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
What I tried:
I attempted to integrate real-time features (chat and video) using Next.js with a MERN stack backend. I explored various libraries like Socket.io for real-time communication and investigated how Next.js can handle these features.
What I expected:
I expected to seamlessly integrate real-time functionalities with Next.js and have a smooth interaction between the client-side and server-side components of my MERN stack.
What actually resulted:
I encountered uncertainty about the best approach for implementing real-time features in Next.js and how well it integrates with the MERN stack backend. I need clarification on best practices and suitable tools for this setup.

Nextjs is already a server-side framework and you don't need to separate your projects. Since Next runs on the server, it allows you to write your own api requests and within these api requests you can access the db directly, no need to create a MERN stack.
As for your first question, Nextjs is very suitable. you can find examples on the templates page on the official site.
For your 3rd question, you can use Tailwindcss + radix ui to gain speed.

even though next.js is server side framework when emplementing real time features such as chat and video  call it has some downfalls compare to mern
